# Unity doesn't load - only desktop wallpaper in 16.04

Tags: hard-drive, 16.04

I changed my HDD of Ubuntu 16.04 from i7 Lenovo PC (GTX-960, 32 GB) to i5 Dell PC (very old GPU, 16 GB). I ran the following commands in the recovery shell of the i5 PC:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I can login successfully but I see no GUI, only Ubuntu's background.

---

How can you transfer Ubuntu 16.04 HDD to New PC successfully?

Comment: @Serg No answer in your thread is right in 16.04. There is compiz, here not.

Comment: the default Ubuntu graphics environment uses compiz. Unless you are using some other desktop environment, you are using compiz.

Comment: @Serg I did not have .compiz folder so its folder removal was not possible. It is not the source of the problem here.

Comment: the post I've linked covers other solutions too, not just compiz. As for the folder, I'm not sure whether it's supposed to exist or not. It typically should be for user specific settings, so if you didn't do any changes to compiz settings, it may not be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot up normally. When you see the desktop background, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd>

You should then be at the terminal. Login.

Then run these commands:

```
rm -r ~/.config
rm -r ~/.compiz
rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo reboot
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
sudo reboot
```

If it *still* doesn't work, try the answer from here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)